# $('<img>') Load Event on Append or Instantiation

Tags: jquery, image, events, load

I'm seeing some weird behavior creating an image pre-loader and I guess I am wondering now if it's possible the load event can fire before it's appended to the DOM.

Could it fire here,

```
var myImg = $('<img>', {src:myImgSrc});
```

Before I've,

```
$(body).append(myImg);
```

?

Comment: It won't load until you add it to the page. Obviously, no `load` event before that.

Comment: No way. Append it with `display:none` and then show() when needed.

Comment: Thanks all, I traced the issues to the __Caveats of the Load Event__ here, http://api.jquery.com/load-event/